# Do I remove plastic feet on bottom of prehung door?

Tags: doors

Am I supposed to remove the plastic feet from prehung door?

[image]

Comment: Usually I would say yes, but with thin stamp metal frame, only if they interfere(too tight at top) with the placement in the rough opening.

Comment: Is that plastic just designed to protect the door jamb during shipping and handling or is it designed to remain permanently under the jamb? If it is the former, remove the staples by inserting a screwdriver under them and prying and/or use pliers to pull them. Often the jamb has to be cut to position the door vertically to give the desired gap under the door. Hard to believe that plastic is designed to be part of the installed door. It would show.

Comment: I'll go ahead and remove them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, remove the shipping protectors. As noted in the comments, they’d show in most circumstances.

And if your floor is out of level, you might be cutting the jamb leg anyway, and cutting staples is a waste of blades.

Comment: If your flooring is black plastic it might be left on for design aesthetics :)